# running custom functions with node and socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

So I would like to be able to run custom function through socket.io using node
My basic idea is fairly simple, I just can't get it to work. Generally speaking you would write something similar to this to run a function on incoming message...

```
//server
socket.on('incomingMessage', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    io.sockets.emit('newMessage', {id: data.id, from: data.name, message: data.message});
});
//client
socket.on('newMessage', function(data) {
    $('#messages').html($('#messages').html() + data.message);
    $('#from').html($('#from').html() + data.from);
});
```

but what I would like to do is allow that to be much more dynamic and actually pass the function I want to run in the message itself, so something like this...

```
//server
socket.on('customFunction', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    io.sockets.emit('runFunction', data);
})

//client
socket.on('runFunction', function(data) {
    for(var index in data) {
        args.push(data[index]);
    }
    data.fn.apply(this, args);
});
```

but when I call this from a client using something like...

```
socket.emit('customFunction', {id: sessionId, name: user.name, callBack: function() { alert('it worked');
    }
});
```

on the server the only thing it logs is the session id and the name, the callBack(regardless of the name, I have tried func, run, cb, callBack, customFunc) just disappears. so I am kind of at a loss. Anyone have any ideas? thank you in advance for the help. I am not sure why, but when calling this it only logs the session id and the name elements, the callback, or fn, or whatever else, just isn't there. Does node or socket.io remove functions from arguments when sending things off?

Answer (score 0):

You are converting data to an array and then try to call a property it doesn't have anymore
then applying the data to the socket.on function (`this`)

so try something like:

```
socket.on('runFunction', function(data) {
    var arg = [];
    args.push(data.id);
    args.push(data.name);
    // etc...
    data.callback.apply(this, args);
});
```

Comment: no such luck. I changed around the code so that the client just has
socket.on('runFunction', function(data) {
    data.fn.apply(this, data);
}})
but when I call it the server logs only {"id" : "-sasf9akdn"} so the fn isn't even getting to the server. somehow somwehere node or socket is running it and removing from the data being sent

Comment: console.log(data) and see what happens

Comment: I did, on both the server in socket.on('customFunction'... function which only logs "{id: "fdsicnsdev4a"}" when called with... socket.emit('customFunction', {id: sessionId, fn: function() { alert('something'); } }); and the client logs the same thing, the fn is just gone

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i i got you right but as far as i can see you have two options.

1. convert your function to string, you can do that with toString() or toSource()
   eval it on the other side (node or client). 
   But maybe and hopefully you don't want that :) - Important is that a function in not serialized if you use JSON.stringify or any framework solution to do that.
2. Create an index of your callable functions and use the index to identify the function 
   on the other side.

Example:

```
//create a index on one side
var runtime = {
"addMessage":function(param1,param2){  alert(arguments)   },
"whatEverFunction":function(){}
 }

 socket.on("runtime",function(data){
 if(!runtime[data.fn])return alert("runtime error");
 runtime[data.fn].apply(null,data.args);
 }


//create a call on the other
socket.io.emit({fn:"addMessage",args:["paramAValue","paramBValue"]});
```

If this does not help you, you may want to check if the library "dnode" does what you want.

Good Luck :)

Comment: not bad ideas, I know about eval, which is why I'll never use it :). The main idea here is pure dynamic coding, the end goal is to essentially write the function I want to run on the server in the call to the server. That way I never have to really update the code on the server to add new functionality, I can dynamically write the function I need to run and send it to the server to be executed on the server. I realize that this is dangerous in many ways but in all honesty I don't need to worry about security as it's only accessible from internally and no one will be messing with it but me.